# Mimic USB Vendor or Product ID

Tags: usb, driver, beagleboard

After having been studying a USB Packet Sniffer based around the BeagleBoard xM (https://gitorious.org/beagleboard-usbsniffer/), I have been at a loss as to how the driver actually works in a certain area.

I now understand that the BeagleBoard acts as a one port USB hub for the USB host to see, so that it may view and log the packets going through it. The part i'm trying to currently understand is how exactly the BeagleBoard is able to be somewhat transparent, and able to mimic the USB Vendor/Product ID's of the device being sniffed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to mimic.  If it behaves as a hub, it can see all the traffic going between the computer and the device under test because all the USB packets would go through the hub.  Packets are received by the hub and transmitted along to the other device.